# How to include fpdf library in magento 2 controller file?

Tags: product, magento-2.1, controllers, pdf

How can I include "fpdf" files in magento 2 controller.I am implementing product details as pdf functionality for that i am going to use fpdf library but unable to include that library in my controller file.Please help me on this.